# How to implement a basic service in Android

Tags: android, service

Its a very basic service i am trying to run, but is not working. The MainActivity puts a string in logcat. But service class is not writing to logcat and there are no errors and no warning too. I have also mentioned full path of service in androidmanifest file too. Logcat is only showing mainactivity log and then it does not start service.

```
package com.example.rushi.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");

    startService(new Intent(this, watchman.class));
}
}
```

Above is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.rushi.app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class watchman extends Service
{
private static final String TAG = "watchman";



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, String startID)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "ccccccccccccccccccccc cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc");
    //stopService(new Intent(resident.this,resident.class));



}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();


    //code
    Log.d(TAG, "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");


}


}
```

Above is my watchman.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.rushi.app">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.example.rushi.app.watchman" ></service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Above is my AndroidManifest.xml. Not getting where i am making mistake?

Comment: make sure that  code running on your device is up to date. If you are using Instant Run, then disable it.

Comment: The signature and return type for `onStartCommand()` is as follows: `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`. You're not actually overriding that method, which is why yours never gets called. That's why the `@Override` annotation is handy. The compiler would've told you that you're not overriding anything there.

Comment: @MikeM. It was the perfect solution. It prints into the logcat from service. Thank you so much. Where should i keep my code into service so that it will run as long as service remains in memory?